# Dividing two tables in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables, say table 1 and table 2.

Table 1:

| Region2 | Apr | May |
| --- | --- | --- |
| North | 50 | 1200 |
| South | 75 | 1500 |
| East | 100 | 750 |
| West | 150 | 220 |

Table 2:

| Region2 | Apr | May |
| --- | --- | --- |
| North | 5 | 12 |
| South | 10 | 15 |
| East | 10 | 15 |
| West | 15 | 11 |

I need a table 3 that is a division of table 1 and table 2
Table 3:

| Region2 | Apr | May |
| --- | --- | --- |
| North | 10 | 100 |
| South | 7.5 | 100 |
| East | 10 | 50 |
| West | 15 | 20 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Have you attempted to solve this for yourself? Where specifically are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by creating a measure which is a ratio.

In my case, table 1 had values in say rupees.
table 2 had values in say, litres

So, I created a measure which is a division of sum total rupees and sum total of litres and when I added the measure to values in pivot matrix, it automatically divided the two tables.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).